# R vector in network analysis

Tags: r, vector

I am working on Network analysis in R. I am getting an error that says argument 2 is not a vector.
Here is I have up until the error (the error is on the links = links line):

```
library(igraph)

nodes = read.csv("vertex.csv", header=T, as.is=T)
links = read.csv("edges.csv", header=T, as.is=T)

head(nodes)
head(links)
nrow(nodes)
length(unique(nodes$id))
nrow(links)
nrow(unique(links[,c("Source", "Target")])) 

links = aggregate(links[,2], # column to aggregate
                  links[,-2], # other columns combined used as "keys"
                  sum) # sum the weights of from-to-type tuple
links = links[order(links$Source, links$Target)] # resort the links
head(links)
```

Here is a snapshot of the edges csv:

[image: edges.csv]

---

Here is the result of `dput(head(links))`:

```
structure(list(Source = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L),
               Weight = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
               x = c(74L, 66L, 33L, 46L, 59L, 12L)), 
               row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

exact error is:

> Error in order(links$Source, links$Target) : argument 2 is not a vector

Comment: can you add the results of `dput(head(links))` please and the exact error. (ps as `links` should be a data frame, I'd expect a different error with `links[order(links$Source, links$Target)]` as you are missing a comma ie `links[order(links$Source, links$Target) , ]` )

Comment: oops ya accidentally removed the comma (still error with it added).
Here is the result of dput(head(links): structure(list(Source = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L), Weight = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), x = c(74L, 66L, 33L, 46L, 59L, 12L)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

And the exact error is: Error in order(links$Source, links$Target) : argument 2 is not a vector

Comment: Hosep, have a look at `links`: `Target` is not a variable name perhaps you mean `links$Weight`

Comment: Another problem is that you have not mention to select column in `links[order(links$Source, links$Target)] `. It should be changed as `links = links[order(links$Source, links$Target),]'

Comment: I am confused what you mean when you say Target is not a variable name. I am pretty sure you are suppose to link source up with target

Comment: I still get the same error with the comma in the correct spot.

Comment: Hosep, look at the `dput` of the data you gave - Target is not there

Comment: ... that siad, if you use the formula method of aggregate you can probably use `links = aggregate(Target ~ . , links, sum) ; links = links[order(links$Source, links$Target), ] ` as it keeps the names

Comment: @Hosep yes, your goal is to link up the variables that serve the *purposes* of target and source, but you have to supply the actual names that are in your data. There's no variable named Target in the data you supplied

Comment: Ah ok I see what you guys mean now. Is there a way to include Target in the data?

Comment: Either change the names so that there is a column named Target, or change the code to refer to columns by their actual names